# Solve equation system for : $ x^2 + y^2 + Ax + By + C = 0 $

Tags: matrices, circles

A list of multiple circles all end up intersecting in one location (this is the nature of the problem).

In order to find this location, knowing for each circle its center location and radius, I am not sure on how to solve this using a matrix.

Example :
Circle #1 : $(x-0)^2 + (y-100)^2 = 100^2$

Circle #2 : $(x-100)^2 + (y-100)^2 = (sqrt(100^2+100^2))^2$ (hypothenuse of $100 \times 100)$

Circle #3 : $(x-200)^2 + (y-0)^2 = 200^2$

In this simple case, we have three circles intersecting at (0,0).
How do I manage to solve this using a matrix ?

Circle equations can be re-written in the form : $x^2 + y^2 + Ax + By + C = 0$.
Can I used this system of equation in a matrix ? $x^2$ and $y^2$ always have 'one' as the coefficient.

Your help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Can you make your question more precise?  I can't figure out what you're asking and what your conditions are.  Are you asking for the collection of all circles that intersect at a given point?  If so, make the point the origin and consider circles that pass through the origin $(C=0)$.  If you want any other point, shift the solution for the origin.

Comment: Rewrite your equations as $x^2+y^2=-Ax-By-C$. Does this give you any ideas?